# i cannot create a domain in openstack

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, openstack

i am trying to create a domain in openstack

i tried this code

```
export OS_TOKEN=admintoken
export OS_URL=http://20.20.20.119:35357/v3
export OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
openstack domain create --description "Default Domain" default
```

the result should be like this
please see the first table on this link
https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openstack_mitaka&f=4

but i am facing an error

the error is
"the request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-af227c0b-5db2-8e32-a391b133b466)"

kindly help so that i can create a domain

thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The OS_TOKEN value should be same as in your environment keystone.conf (/etc/keystone/keystone.conf) admin_token label.

Comment: yes it is the same value in /etc/keystone/keystone.conf

Comment: in that /etc/keystone/keystone.conf file the values are like

Comment: admin_token=admintoken

Comment: Create a new token using: **openstack token issue**. Add the authentication uri etc with this command. And add the new token to your file. This token expires after the expiry. Expiration of the token might be one of the reasons. When you issue a new token it would display an output showing new token value and also the expiry datetime. For details, how to issue token, visit: https://docs.openstack.org/keystone/rocky/install/keystone-verify-ubuntu.html